# Return string after timeout in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, system.timers.timer

I use the following function to send commands to an instrument and receive the query results back and it works fine.

```
Public Function InstrSndRcv(cmd2Send As String) As String  
     MyInstrument.WriteLine(cmd2Send) 
    ' if myTimeout(desierdtime) then
    'Return "my string"
    'else 
    Dim qryRetrn As String = MyInstrument.ReadLine()  
    Return qryRetrn
    'End if
End Function
```

I have commented out the conditional functionality I need in terms of a subroutine myTimeout(desiredtime). How to implement it in VB.NET?

The idea is to return "my string" in case the instrument does not respond to a query command. May be there is a better way to do this...

Comment: The clean way would be for your instrument library to supply you either with a timeoutable read operation (e.g. `MyInstrument.ReadLineWithTimeout(2000)`) or with a non-blocking read operation (e.g. `MyInstrument.IsLineAvailable()`). Please check if your instrument library provides something like that. It should. Otherwise, you'd have to create a separate thread, do the read operation there and kill the thread after a certain timeout. This, however, could leave your library in an unstable state.

Comment: instrument library does not have a timeoutread opeartion. Also the instrument will not return anything if for example its switched off or not connected (in my case via RS232). I was thinking of getting "my string" to report "instrument not connected or switched off" if the myTimeout condition gets satisfied.

Comment: Do you have some non-blocking read operation? Often, this is simply called `Read` instead of `ReadLine`.

Comment: not sure what "non blocking" is? I do use ReadLine.

Comment: A *blocking* read operation means that your program stops until input is available. That's exactly what happens with `ReadLine`: It blocks until a line has been read (or forever, if no input is provided). What you need is a *non-blocking* operation: A operation which returns *immediately*, even if no input is available. For example, an (imaginary) method `ReadNextCharIfAvailable` which returns a char if it is available and 0 if it isn't would be non-blocking. My suggest is that you read the manual that came with your library and find out if there are any non-blocking read operations available.

Comment: And if you find any, we can use those to implement a timeout-based ReadLine operation.

Comment: hmm..I do not think I have a non-blocking option in my instrument library. I am using an serial port to connect to the instrument. Is it possible to use `serialPort.ReadTimeout` for what i need

Comment: You'll have to tell us the type for MyInstrument, if it is a System.IO.Ports.Serial​Port then [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=netframework-4.7.2) has a very good example of what you are looking for.

Comment: @jam_27: That depends on how your instrument library is implemented. I'm afraid, you will have to either (1) provide us with the implementation and/or documentation of the library, if available, or (2) pose this question to the manufacturer of your library.